# how to use TablLayout inside Fragment?

Tags: java, android

I want to use TabLayout inside Fragment.
Here is my fragment_main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.ek.karhabtyapplication.ParkingFragment"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/simpleTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabBackground="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/simpleFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Here is My MainFragment.java :

```
 tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {


                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new ParkingMapFragment();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "fragm 1 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new ParkingHistoricFragment();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "fragm 2 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment);
                transaction.commit();
            }
    });
```

The prbleme that when I clic in first tab the message is shoing but the fragment didn't change.
AnyOne have an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fragment changes but you can't see it because the simpleFrameLayout is not currently in view. Your TabLayout is filling the entire width of the screen and your FrameLayout is positioned to the right of the TabLayout.

Comment: Thank you very much.I changed the orientation of LinearLayout to vertical and it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code  and set `android:orientation="horizontal"`  to `android:orientation="vertical"`  in `LinearLayout`

```
 tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
            Fragment  fragmentOne = new ParkingMapFragment();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "fragm 1 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
                    break;
                case 1:
            Fragment  fragmentTwo = new ParkingHistoricFragment();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "fragm 2 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FragmentTransaction transactionOne = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transactionOne .add(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment);
            transactionOne .commit();
                    break;
            }


        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a view pager below Tab Layout after that you can easily swap and use it.create a view pager adapter and add fragment in that adapter.

Comment: private void setTabsViewPagerView() {
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new AbcFragment(), getResources().getString("abc"));
        adapter.addFragment(new DefFragmentt(), getResources().getString("test"));
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }